# STL Containers - difference between vector, list and deque

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Should I use deque instead of vector if i'd like to push elements also in the beginning of the container? When should I use list and what's the point of it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `deque` if you need efficient insertion/removal at the beginning and end of the sequence and random access; use `list` if you need efficient insertion anywhere, at the sacrifice of random access. Iterators and references to `list` elements are very stable under almost any mutation of the container, while `deque` has very peculiar iterator and reference invalidation rules (so check them out carefully).

Also, `list` is a node-based container, while a `deque` uses chunks of contiguous memory, so memory locality may have performance effects that cannot be captured by asymptotic complexity estimates.

`deque` can serve as a replacement for `vector` almost everywhere and should probably have been considered the "default" container in C++ (on account of its more flexible memory requirements); the only reason to prefer `vector` is when you must have a guaranteed contiguous memory layout of your sequence.

Comment: `vector` almost always performs better than `deque`, in my experience.

Comment: @DonReba: it depends on the use case, and profiling is really the only answer. A vector might struggle if you want to allocate a huge range, while the deque can allocate new chunks without moving the old ones. And of course it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @KerrekSB Could you give some profiling data here. That will be very evident in deciding the performance.

Comment: @Sisir: This isn't a very good answer. While "deque" is in principle a good idea, there are many bad implementations out there that use too small a chunk size and thus effectively turn into linked lists. So you'll definitely need to compare and profile; `std::vector` often performs better even for insertions other than at the end for many "typical" container sizes.

Answer (score 14):

`deque` and `vector` provide random access, `list` provides only linear accesses. So if you need to be able to do container[i], that rules out `list`. On the other hand, you can insert and remove items anywhere in a `list` efficiently, and operations in the middle of `vector` and `deque` are slow.

`deque` and `vector` are very similar, and are basically interchangeable for most purposes. There are only two differences worth mentioning. First, `vector` can only efficiently add new items at the end, while `deque` can add items at either end efficiently. So why would you ever use a `vector` then? Unlike `deque`, `vector` guarantee that all items will be stored in contiguous memory locations, which makes iterating through them faster in some situations.

Comment: Could you give some profiling data here. That will be very evident in deciding the performance.