# Does deque provide O(1) complexity when inserting on top

Tags: c++, vector, stl, deque

I was going over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650254/stl-containers-diffrence-between-vector-list-and-deque) post and it states that deque provides efficent insetion at the top and bottom.However this [post](http://john-ahlgren.blogspot.com/2013/10/stl-container-performance.html) here states that time complexity of deque other than the back is O(n).I would think that if a deque has efficent top and bottom insertion it would have O(1) while a vector should have O(1) at bottom insertion only. I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this

Comment: it is an error in the blog post, even [the SO question that it references](http://stackoverflow.com/q/181693/4279); gets it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cppreference entry for [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) gives the following complexity:

> The complexity (efficiency) of common operations on deques is as follows:

- Random access - constant O(1)
- Insertion or removal of elements at the end or beginning - amortized constant O(1)
- Insertion or removal of elements - linear O(n)

which is consistent with the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `23.3.3.1` *Class template deque overview* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> A deque is a sequence container that, like a vector (23.3.6), supports random access iterators. In addition, it supports constant time insert and erase operations at the beginning or the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time. That is, **a deque is especially optimized for pushing and popping elements at the beginning and end**. As with vectors, storage management is handled automatically.

For [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) cppreference says:

> The complexity (efficiency) of common operations on vectors is as follows:

- Random access - constant O(1)
- Insertion or removal of elements at the end - amortized constant O(1)
- Insertion or removal of elements - linear in distance to the end of the vector O(n)

which is consistent with the draft standard section `23.3.6.1` *Class template vector overview*:

> A vector is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, **it supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the end;** insert and erase in the middle take linear time. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency.[...]

Comment: Does a vector have a 0(1) insertion at both ends or just at the end ?

Comment: Either they changed the wording in cppreference or you misquoted, but the complexity of insertion/removal at the ends for deque is listed as constant O(1) *not* amortized constant O(1). This is obviously significant, but as a side note, for the life of me, I can't figure out how constant O(1) is even possible.

Comment: @dcmm88 "for the life of me, I can't figure out how constant O(1) is even possible." Well, if you suspend disbelief enough to believe that one memory allocation/deallocation of a constant-size chunk of memory takes O(1) time (which is not at all obvious and I can't find any guarantees of it, so lets just consider it to be an axiom), then you can get O(1) insertion/removal at ends of a deque by implementing it as a simple doubly-linked list, right? My understanding is that std::deque is essentially that, except that each link in the chain has a shopping-basket of items instead of a single item.

Answer (score 6):

C++98, section 23.2.1 (Template class deque)

"A deque ... supports constant time insert and erase operations at the beginning or the end; insert and erase in the mid-dle take linear time. That is, a deque is especially optimized for pushing and popping elements at the beginning and end. As with vectors, storage management is handled automatically."

So yes: O(1) insertion at both ends.

Comment: What if the deque is full and push_front is requested? Wouldn't a new chunk of block be allocated and the rest of the elements would be copied over to that new chunk? How does it work, making it amortized O(1)? How else does it work?

Comment: new chunk will be used only for that new element. Why the others should be copied to the new place?

Answer (score 4):

From the C++ standard:

> 23.3.3.4 deque modiﬁers [deque.modiﬁers]

```
[...]
void push_front(const T& x);
void push_front(T&& x);
void push_back(const T& x);
void push_back(T&& x);
```

> [...]
>
> 3 Complexity: The complexity is linear in the number of elements inserted plus the lesser of the distances to the beginning and end of the deque. **Inserting a single element either at the beginning or end of a deque always takes constant time and causes a single call to a constructor of T.**

Emphasis mine