# Time complexity of queue in C++

Tags: c++, stl

What is the time complexity of standard queue operations such as `push_back` and `pop_front` provided by `std::queue` in C++ STL? It is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the complexity guarantees of the standard containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181693/what-are-the-complexity-guarantees-of-the-standard-containers)

Comment: BTW: It is specified in the standard even (assuming you mean the standard and not the obsolete STL)! Check out e.g. cppreference.com, which is not the standard but pretty close and damn useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `push()` (which internally calls `push_back()` on the underlying container) and `pop()`(which internally calls `pop_front()` on the underlying container) provided by `std::queue` in C++ STL have a constant `O(1)` time complexity since they only insert at the end of queue or pop from the front of it. You can check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/ to find out more about other methods and their time complexities.

Comment: One more thing to note that above time complexity is consider amortized time complexity. In practice, queues use deque as underlying containers. You can read about how deque has constant amortized time complexity here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050760/how-does-deque-have-an-amortized-constant-time-complexity

Answer (score 1):

`std::stack` is just a shim on top of another container, so the time complexity depends on the underlying container type used by the stack.  By default, the container type is [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), which has O(1) push and pop.

You can use any container type that meets the requirements of [SequenceContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer), including a user-defined type.

For example, if you use `std::vector` as the underlying container type, then popping is still O(1) but pushing is amortized O(1) (due to possible reallocations).